# I'm able to run the smlnj repl in a Powershell window but when I try to run it with a file or "use" a file inside the REPL, it fails

Tags: smlnj

This is the error I get with I start it, in Windows 10 Powershell, with a file name: *sml first.sml*
or try to: *use "first.sml"*

"uncaught exception SysErr [SysErr: access: cannot get file attributes]   raised at: Basis/Implementation/Win32/os-filesys.sml:32.30-32.74"

When I run it inside emacs with the sml package, the "use" function works just fine.

If I use OS.FileSys.getDir() it shows that it's pointing to my working directory.

I'm using the latest version 10.98.1  (version 10.98.0 also had this issue).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nevermind.  It appears that the error I'm getting is just indicating that it can't find the file?!  I was trying to access files that were in a subdirectory and so, of course, it couldn't find them.

Dave